# Create different dataframes from 1 excel file using selected columns

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

I have a large data frame with dates and then stocks at the top with columns of price data.

```
Header 1    Header 2    Header 3    Header 4

========    ========    ========    ========

Date         Stock 1    Stock 2     Stock 3

1/2/2001     2.77        6.00        11.00 

1/3/2001     2.89         6.08       11.10 

1/4/2001     2.86         6.33       11.97 

1/5/2001     2.80         6.58       12.40
```

What I want to do is make multiple dataframes from this one file with the date and the stock price of each stock. So essentially in this example you would have 4 dataframes (the file has more than 1000 of them so this is just a sample). So the dataframes would be:

```
DF1 = Data and Stock 1

DF2 = Data and Stock 2

DF3 = Data and Stock 3

DF4 = Data and Stock 4
```

I am then going to take each dataframe and add more columns to each of them once they are created.

I was reading through previous questions and came up with `usecols`, but I can seem to get the syntax written properly. Can someone help me out? Also if there is a better way to do this please advise. Since I have more than 1000, speed is important in running through the file

This is what I have so far but I am not sure I am heading down the most efficient path. It gives the following error (among others it seems):

```
>>>> ValueError: The elements of 'usecols' must either be all strings or all integers`
```

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('file.csv') 
    # read in Exel file to get column headers from excel
for i in df2: 
a = 0 
    # always want to have 1st (date column) as 1st column in DF
d = pd.read_csv('file.csv',usecols=[a,i]) 
    # Read in file with proper columns, will always be first column 
    #and  add column 1, next loop cols 0,2, next loop 0,3, etc. 
dataf[i] = pd.DataFrame(d) #actually create DataFrame
```

It also seems to be inefficient to have to read in the file each time. Maybe there is a way to read in file once and then create the dataframes. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider building a list of integer pairings (`[0,1], [0,2], [0,3]`, etc.) to slice master dataframe by columns. Then iteratively append dataframes to a list which is a preferred setup of one container (with similarly structured elements) to avoid 1000's of dfs flooding your global enviroment.

```
dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y')    
masterdf = pd.read_csv("DataFile.csv", parse_dates=[0], date_parser=dateparse)

colpairs = [[0, i] for i in range(1, len(masterdf.columns))]

dfList = []
for cols in colpairs:    
    dfList.append(masterdf[cols])

print(len(dfList))
print(dfList[0].head())
print(dfList[1].head())
```

Alternatively, consider a dictionary of dataframes with stock names as keys for a container, where *colpairs* carry string literal pairings as opposed to integers:

```
colpairs = [['Date', masterdf.columns[i]] for i in range(1, len(masterdf.columns))]

dfDict = {}    
for cols in colpairs:    
    dfDict[cols[1]] = masterdf[cols]

print(len(dfDict))
print(dfDict['Stock 1'].head())
print(dfDict['Stock 2'].head())
```